# If stains/traces of madhiy remain on garment after sprinkling water over it, does it matter?

Tags: practical-islam, sunni, taharah, najis

We know that if we sprinkle a handful of water over madhiy on a garment, it is sufficient according to the most authentic opinion. But I have a doubt. If stains or traces of madhiy still remain after sprinkling the water, do I have to sprinkle water again in that area? Or is sprinkling a handful of water once sufficient regardless of the stains or traces of madhiy that remain? And is the water that was splashed on madhiy pure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Water is regarded in fiqh as having the attribute to be tahir: clean

Moreover it is regarded as

> tahir mutahhir
> طاهر مُطَهِّر

meaning it is clean طاهر (by itself) and cleaning مُطَهِّر (anything which comes in contact with it).

We could also say madhiy (a spot) usually is less the quantity of water  (a handful) used for the act of cleaning therefore the water used in such a case is still regarded as tahir in the majority view.

But we know from fiqh and from hadith sources that the only requirement for removing or maybe it is better to say handle madhiy is by sprinkling water over it. This requirement was nowhere extended to remove the traces of madhiy (if madhiy is regarded as najasah then this would be a special case).
Therefore the above discussion can be closed by saying handling madhiy is done and fulfilled by only sprinkling water over it there's no necessity to remove it or its traces.

As to the topic of stains of najasa it was already discussed in the following posts:

- [Semen Stains Remaining On Clothes Even After thoroughly Washing The Garment](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67552/semen-stains-remaining-on-clothes-even-after-thoroughly-washing-the-garment)
- [is pus and blood najis](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50020/is-pus-and-blood-najis)

And what must be cleaned or removed, if najasah (color, odor and taste)  is removed is explained in:
[Ritual impurity in pants](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/42575/ritual-impurity-in-pants)

Comment: I would like to specifically know about madhiy, not about blood, pus or semen as those have different rulings regarding cleaning them. If stains of madhiy remain after sprinkling water do I have to sprinkle water again or does it become tahir? Just a simple clarification would do.

Comment: @user2007 there's nothing specific a najasah is a najasah and the way of cleaning is the same.

Comment: So the conclusion is that even if traces of madhiy remain after splashing water it is still pure right?

Comment: And also the way of cleaning blood, semen and madhiy is definitely different as human blood or pus (except if it comes out from the private parts) and semen is pure according to the more authentic opinion. And the way of cleaning madhiy is sprinkling water. The way of cleaning urine is washing it. Even if one wants to clean semen for just cleanliness it is to be scratched off if dry or washed if wet. But please clarify the conclusion here.

Comment: The way of cleaning means removing it's color, odor and taste as good as possible. This is what fiqh agrees upon as about how you do it that's up to you in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Sheikh 'Assim in a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/mwlEmkLK3rw?t=57) said:

> Sprinkling it does the job even if there are marks. Ignore it and pray with it.

This fatwa on [Islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/242992/sprinkling-water-over-mathy-for-purification) also says it is sufficient to sprinkle water over it according to some scholars.

> There is no doubt that "sprinkling water does not remove the impurity," as Ibn Qudaamah  may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him said, but some scholars are anyway of the view that it is sufficient to sprinkle water over it in order not to cause hardship and embarrassment, pursuant to the Ahaadeeth that provide that sprinkling water is enough, like the Hadeeth: “….what about that clothes it touches? and the Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ) replied: It is enough for you to take a handful of water and splash it over the part of your clothes that you see it has touched.” [Abu Daawood] And the Hadeeth narrated by ’Ali  may  Allaah  be  pleased  with  him about Mathy which reads: "… and splash water over your genitals."

Hopefully this answers the question. And Allah knows the best.